# Can I disable SSO in specific web apps secured by Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have several ASP.Net MVC apps in my Azure tenant that use Azure AD for authentication (implemented using OWIN middleware).  In one of the apps I want to force the user to re-authenticate if they navigate to that app from one of the other apps.  Is there configuration settings or code that can make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by adding a **prompt=login** query string parameter to the AAD authorization endpoint URL. This will skip the SSO and force a login with AAD.

More information on the query string parameter here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx.

This forum post seems to show how you can add these query string parameters to the login request when using OWIN middleware: http://forums.asp.net/t/1999402.aspx?Owin+pass+custom+query+parameters+in+Authentication+Request